# ios safari usually fails to execute first http request after wake up

Tags: ios, angularjs, safari

I have developed a web app using Angularjs. This app is intended to be used by company employees that have an iPad.

The application works great on Chrome, but Safari is causing problems. iOS Safari usually fails to execute first http request after wake up. If a user tries to navigate within the app after a wake up, the http request fails, the application shows the error to the user, then the user needs to refresh the page one or more times to get it working again.

Is there something I can do to workaround this problem other than recommend users to use Chrome instead of Safari?

EDIT: thanks to a friend that has a Mac I got the exact error message:

> Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost

Comment: I cannot get the exact error. I have code that logs the error to the console but I need a Mac to see the error and I don't have a Mac. I tried to show the error in Json format to the user but circular references prevent Stringify to work.

Comment: I would try using a web proxy debugger like Charles to watch the interaction with the back end. It could be that Safari is more particular and detecting an issue which the other browsers are ignoring. If you google this error there are quite a few hits.